# Python - ValueError: sign must be an integer with the value 0 or 1

Tags: python, valueerror

```
with open("{}.json".format(ctx.message.author.id), "r") as json_file:
    profileData = json.load(json_file)
    data = profileData[ctx.message.author.id]

with open("attacks.json") as json_data:
    items = json.load(json_data)

thing = "soldier"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(soldier))
thing = "sniper"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(sniper))
thing = "demolitionist"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(demolit))
thing = "spy"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(spy))
thing = "armored_vehicle"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(armored_vehicle))
thing = "tank"
data[thing + "#"] = "{}".format(int(data[thing + "#"]) - int(tank))

random_percent_j = ["1.1", "1.25", "1.4"]
data["balance"] = "{}".format(int(data["balance"]) + int(items["1"]["deploy_cost"]) * int(soldier) * random.choice(Decimal(random_percent_j)))
```

This is what I get and I've never seen this type of error before. Some of it's JSON so here's the code for that: https://hastebin.com/hoseyikove.json

```
  File "run.py", line 220, in attack
data["balance"] = "{}".format(int(data["balance"]) + int(items["1"]["deploy_cost"]) * int(soldier) * random.choice(Decimal(random_percent_j)))
ValueError: sign must be an integer with the value 0 or 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You're instantiating a `Decimal` object with a list (`random_percent_j`) in your last line of code. It should be:

```
Decimal(random.choice(random_percent_j))
```

*not*

```
random.choice(Decimal(random_percent_j))
```